# proxy_pass connection insecure

Tags: nginx

I have a problem with nginx and proxy_pass. I try to secure connection to old server without option to upgrade apache there. I can't establish there ssl connection with tls 1.2. So i Tried to secure it by reverse proxy in nginx with some success. when i open website like http://example.com or https://example.com connection is secure and it works well. But there are other sites whitch have links like https://example.com/login https://example.com/investitions (basicly every uri example.com/foo/bar/ ect.)and those connections are insecure. my nginx config looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com www.example.com;

ssl_certificate        ssl.crt;
ssl_certificate_key    ssl.key;
ssl_client_certificate ca.crt;
proxy_ssl_protocols  TLSv1.2;
proxy_ssl_ciphers   HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
proxy_ssl_verify on;
proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;

location / {
proxy_set_header X-Scheme https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr 
proxy_pass http://baza.example.com/;
    }
```

Please help me.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "insecure" I feel that your browser warns that your page fetches some insecure (http) endpoints (js/css/images etc). so, make sure you replace all urls with https when you get forwarded https proto on your upstream (the actual app, apache one)

Comment: Thanks. after analysing source i can see that i have some images with http in adress. Do You know any way to rewrite adresses from http to https from nginx?

Comment: right now i have error SSL_ERROR_UNSUPPORTED_VERSION but there are only tls 1.2 and 1.3 enabled

Comment: You will need replace_filter module to replace body coming from upstream, but I would not recommend to do so. What about replacing them in origin?